# JQuery Slideshow Technique

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I am trying to make my own custom JQuery slideshow. The slides consist of an img tag with a p tag for text. I wanted that this data can be provided in ul li tags e.g.

```
<ul>
  <li>image1.jpg</li>
  <li>THIS IS TEXT<li/>
<ul/>
<ul><li><li/><ul/>
```

and template for slide provided in slideshow element

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <img src="image1">
  <p>THIS IS TEXT</p>
<div/>
```

My technique then was to store all data in variable and using setInterval(function(){},3000) to loop through slides - and modifying the src attribute of img tag after every loop with the current image and the p tag with current text.

It was working on localhost but on my goDaddy server it wasn't. F12 showed me that the src attribute is changing consistently but the update isn't rendered - only text was being changed.

I then thought that images have to be stored somewhere on page with a display:none so that they can be accessed instantly so I added that to code but still no change.

**Here is my code**

```
$(function(){
 $(".slider").each(function(i, slideElem){
var slides=[];
$(slideElem).find("div ul").each(function(i, elem){
  var slide={};
  slide.image=$.trim($(elem).find("li:first").html());
  slide.text1=$.trim($(elem).find("li").eq(1).html());

  slide.text2 = $(elem).find("li").length > 2 ? $.trim($(elem).find("li").eq(2).html())                       : "";    
  slides.push(slide);
});

var cache=$("<div>").css("display", "none").appendTo(slideElem);
$(slides).each(function(i, val){
  cache.append($("<img>").attr("src", val.image));
});

$(slideElem).find("div").has("ul").remove();
setInterval(function () {
  var start=1;
  var slider=$(slideElem);
  var n;
  if((n=slider.data("next"))==undefined) n=0;
  if(n>=slides.length) n=start;
  var slide=slides[n];
  var p=slide.text1 + (slide.text2 ? ("<br />\n" + slide.text2) : "");
  var image = slide.image;

  slider.find("p").html("").html(p);
  slider.children("img").attr("src", image);

  if(n<(slides.length-1)) n++; else n=0;
  slider.data("next", n)    
    }, 3300);    
  });
 });
```

**What is wrong with this technique and what is the right technique?**

Looking at other slideshows it looks like that you have to have all slides on page with display:none and then rotate through slides changing current slide to display:block. Is this right?

Comment: Changing the src attribut will trigger a new HTTP-request, and a new TCP connection needs to be set up for every time the picture changes, this is not very practical. You are on the right track to change the visibility in some way of the objects that are already loaded. Your question is not very clear. The best advice I can give you is to go check out others' solutions to get some inspiration.